# Display dynamic content based on user status in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication, session-variables

**Description:** Users are stored in a database and upon login the user credentials are stored in `$_SESSION` variables, one of which contain information on whether the user has admin rights or not. 
Certain elements should only be displayed to users, I have given these `class="admin"`.
Before the closing body tag I run a `<script></script>` which displays or hides the elements with `class="admin"` based on the value of the `$_SESSION['isAdmin']` variable.

**The Problem:** Some content is generated dynamically by AJAX based on user interaction. For instance, users can display different tables. Each row in the table has a button with `class="admin"`, which should only be displayed to admins. This dynamic generated content is not hit by the ending `<script></script>` and is therefore not displayed correctly according to the user status.

**Solution**:

1. I could place an `<?php if(statement) ?>` before each `class="admin"` element, to make sure they're only displayed to admins. This doesn't seem like the right design practice, though.
2. I could store the value of `$_SESSION['isAdmin]` in a javascript variable and each time content is generated run the script (i.e. with an eventListener), which displys/hide content based on user status. Is this the way to go?
3. A better solution? I'm sure there is a standard way of doing this. I just don't know how.

Comment: The first solution, in PHP is the best practise. Everything you store and display using Javascript can easily be manipulated by the user, thus allowing him to see and access the things he has no rights for.

Comment: You do realise that if javascript is making things visible to specific user EVERYBODY can see the admin data if the just `view page source` **dont you??**

Comment: You need to do the Admin check in the PHP that builds the page and only add it to the page if the user is an admin.

Comment: The first solution is the best practice and using the first approach you can add class and set CSS accordingly.

Comment: Me personally I like to set me a variable with the class if the user is an Administrator. ie.: $css_class = "admin". If the user is not, I would set $css_class = "user". Then in the html just echo $css_class in the class attribute.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to avoid to do the check for each element separately, as that seemed to be a lot of unneccessary code. With my workaround the users could just edit the source, though...